# Trusted_host_patterns not working with domain

Tags: configuration

I'm working with a drupal 8 site and trying to get trusted_host_patterns working properly with the domain that I'm using, and no matter what combination of regex I try I can only get it to work with the catch-all '^.*$'. So far, I've used (plus a couple more):

```
'^production\.sitename\.com$',
'^www\.production\.sitename\.com$',
'^.+.production.sitename.com.$',   // which I know is the same but more general than above
```

which as far as I know from looking at examples, should work. Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this one out after some trial and error. I don't know if it is necessary due to some server settings I have, but I fixed this by adding the private IP of my server to the trusted host names setting. I'm uncertain as to why this is necessary since all the other examples I've seen don't need any reference to the private IP, but in my case it seems to be needed.